# How to intuitively loop through a flat object with unique keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an object much like the below which is containing the titles and body contents of a tab component. This is the data that comes from the CMS so I don't have control over the structure of the object other than the naming of the keys. Is there a way I can loop through this object so that I am not using separate `if statements` to find each key and actually use one bit of code for each key?

```
{
  component: "tabs"
  first_tab_body: {type: "doc", content: Array(2)}
  first_tab_title: "Summary"
  second_tab_body: {type: "doc", content: Array(1)}
  second_tab_title: "Reviews"
  third_tab_body: ""
  third_tab_title: ""
}
```

With the above I am writing this in my code:

```
<MUITabs>
  {props.content.first_tab_title && (
    <Tab label={content.first_tab_title} disableRipple />
  )}
  {props.content.second_tab_title && (
    <Tab label={props.content.second_tab_title} disableRipple />
  )}
  {props.content.third_tab_title && (
    <Tab label={props.content.third_tab_title} disableRipple />
  )}
</MUITabs>
```

Whereas I'd like to achieve this (or something similar):

```
<MUITabs>
  {content.map(() => {
    <Tab label={title} disableRipple />
  })
</MUITabs>
```

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: this could help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: however, you'd fight against the sequence. Objects fairly guaratee the insertion order, but as soon you manipulate them, the order is unpredictable. Favor array, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish they were in an array, put them in one:

```
[props.content.first_tab_title, props.content.second_tab_title, props.content.third_tab_title].map( label => ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a flat object, you will still need to use if and else statement to filter out the keys. You can use `Object.keys` and then `map` over them, But you you will get `first_tab_body` and `first_tab_title` in two different iterations and there is no guarantee of the order of those iterations.

As Ben suggested you can use array.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```js
let data = {
  component: "tabs",
  first_tab_body: {
    type: "doc",
    content: Array(2)
  },
  first_tab_title: "Summary",
  second_tab_body: {
    type: "doc",
    content: Array(1)
  },
  second_tab_title: "Reviews",
  third_tab_body: "",
  third_tab_title: ""
}

function mapTab(data) {
  let r = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
    let m = /^(\w+)_tab_title/.exec(key)
    if (m) {
      return `<Tab label={${data[m[0]]}} disableRipple />`
    }
  })
  return r.filter(el => el)
}

console.log(mapTab(data).join("\n"))
```